# MediaWiki hook for reverting file operation

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am trying to find a way to hook into the action of reverting the **file** to some older version, which is done by heading to the page of the file (File:Filename) and clicking on the Revert/Rollback link in the file history table. Looked into tons of hooks at the MediaWiki documentation, tried many, but no luck. The closest I could do is to hook into file upload and page saved. But I need to hook exactly after the user has reverted the file back to the previous version.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do/what do you want to do in that hook?
Quickest way to see if hook exists is look in code: If hook is not called, hook does not exist.

Comment: I wanted to trigger a script on this action. I have some integration in this Wiki and need to trigger some script on this action. Now I have sorted it out in a workaround way - by a script which constantly checks the upload dir for changes and triggers the target script once some files are changed/added.

Answer (score 1):

You can try if one of the following hooks meets your needs:

```
includes/filerepo/Hook/LocalFilePurgeThumbnailsHook.php
includes/filerepo/Hook/FileUploadHook.php
includes/filerepo/Hook/LocalFile__getHistoryHook.php
includes/filerepo/Hook/FileTransformedHook.php
```

Esp. the FileUploadHook seems to be one you are searching for. See [the (somewhat short) documentation for that hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/FileUpload). Note that this is only for *local* file uploads, so if you host your files somewhere else, this will not easily work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Two of them I have already tried with no luck. I will try the LocalFile__getHistoryHook and LocalFilePurgeThumbnailsHook and get back to you then.